# How do I set input border color and disable number spinner in datatable.net datatable

Tags: javascript, css, sass, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 2.1 website and I am using bootstrap and datatables.net data tables with the datatables.net-bs4 node module applied.

I have customized the color theme for my site by setting my desired colors in bootstraps _custom-variables.scss file and then I import it in a custom.scss file and use gulp to transpile it into css that I use in my site's _layout.cshtml. This is in accordance with [Bootstraps recommended approach to customizing the theme.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)

This works just fine for everything except the items per page selector control in the datatable component.

Here is an image of the search control on the datatable showing the desired input focus border color.

[image]

and here is the same datatable showing the items per page control.

[image]

Notice how the items per page control focus border color is brighter, making the color look more like Cyan.

How can I correct this sop that the focus border color of the items per page control is the same as the focus border on the search box control?

Along those same lines, the items per page control on the datatable shows the html 5 number spinner arrows. I have added code to my site css to disable the spinner arrows. This works on my form fields that have input fields with numbers but it has no effect on the items per page control in the datatable.

Here is the css code I am using to remove the number spinner arrows.

```
    input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    input[type="number"] {
        -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }
```

This works for my normal form input controls, as shown blow.

Before adding the CSS

[image]

After adding the CSS

[image]

However, the items per page control in the datatable.net datatable still shows the spinner, as showing again below;

[image]

How can I remove the spinner arrows from the items per page control?

**UPDATE 11/8/18**. Thanks for @zgood, I was able to fix the issue with the following overrides in my site.css

```
    /* Overide the entries per page select control style on the data table */
    .dataTables_length select {
        background: White;
    }

    /* Override all focus glow color/effects for Datatables.net control*/
    .dataTables_length select:focus {
        border-color: rgba(126, 220, 104, 0.8);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(126, 239, 104, 0.6);
        outline: 0 none;
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked in to the `dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js` plugin for dataTables? See [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4), maybe this will help generate markup that matches your bootstrap 4 styles. Also, the spinner arrows are a `background` style on the `select` that you would need to override. i.e. `.dataTables_length select { background: none; }`

Comment: @zgood your suggestion of using .dataTables_length select { background: none; } solved the spinner issue. Also, you identifying .dataTable_length led me to figuring out how to change the shadowbox style for the items per page focus. Thx. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables adds a spinner type icon on the `background` style of the `select`. You can override this in your css using the following style:

```
.dataTables_length select { background: none; }
```

DataTables will wrap all the "length" controls with a class called `.dataTables_length`, all the "filtering" controls with `dataTables_filter`, all the "info" controls with `dataTables_info`, and all the "pagination" controls with `dataTables_paginate`.

So you can target your styles using those classes.

You can also look in the "dom" option of DataTables to configure where these four sections render out in the DOM in relation to the table itself (like if you wanted the length change `select` on the bottom left of the table instead of at the top left). [See here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)